# how to use hadoop custom data type as column data type for hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to use custom writable data type written in hadoop as a column data type for some table in hive. Any idea How to register the custom data type of hadoop in hive , so that it can be use it as a column data type.

Answer (score 0):

See if below link helps you.

Add new Time Stamp data type to Hive
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2272